# Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

I am getting runtime error while running the following code on leetcode. When I am removing the user-defined comparator function it is working fine. But with user define comparator function it is giving runtime error as follows :

```
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
```

```
class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<int>> groupThePeople(vector<int>& groupSizes) {
    int n = groupSizes.size();
    int visit[n];
    memset(visit, 0, sizeof(visit)); 
    vector<vector<int>>result;
    int m=0,k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        k=0;
        if(visit[i]!=1)
        {
            visit[i]=1;
            result[m][k]=i;
            k=1;
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(groupSizes[i]==groupSizes[j] && visit[j]!=1 && k+1<=groupSizes[i])
                {
                    visit[j] = 1;
                    result[m][k]=j;
                    k++;
                }
            }
            m++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

};

Comment: how many elements does `vector<vector<int>>result;` have?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and do not use coding challenge sites to learn C++, thats not what they are meant for.

Comment: Since you are aware of vectors' existence, why are you using completely non-standard and error-prone `int visit[n];`, instead of using a vector, properly?

Comment: guys can you pls point out the mistake....rather than telling me what to or what not to do...it is a humble request.

Comment: frankly, the mistake is that you wrote code that you dont understand yourself. It is impossible to write correct C++ code when you are guessing how stuff works. `vector<vector<int>>result;` creates a vector with 0 elements. You have to either use the constructor that takes number of elements as parameter or use `push_back` to push elements to a vector. `operator[]` does not magically resize

Answer (score 0):

You are using the result vector without initializing its size or adding any elements to it. You need to resize the result vector before accessing its elements. Replace the line vector<vector> result; with vector<vector> result(n); to initialize result with n empty vectors.

Inside the for loop, when you try to assign values to result[m][k], it will result in a runtime error because the vectors in result have not been resized. Instead of assigning values directly, you should use the push_back() function to add elements to the corresponding vector in result. Replace result[m][k] = i; with result[m].push_back(i); and result[m][k] = j; with result[m].push_back(j);.

Make sure to check if the current group size is equal to k instead of k+1 in the condition k+1<=groupSizes[i]. Replace k+1 with k in that condition.